# How can I make a small array from a bigger one? Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, matrix

Imagine I have this transit matrix, which comes from the distances between each geographic point in a city. However I only will need to access certain points which I will try to optimize a route for it. In this case for example this is the whole matrix. The data inside the matrix is a float

```
   A    B   C    D  E    F
A [0 ,  1 , 3 , 20, 60 ,100],
B [4 ,  0 , 7 , 95, 29 , 98],
C [6 ,  5 , 0 , 36, 68 ,120],
D [12, 97 , 3 , 0 , 94 , 30],
E [33, 34 , 87, 34, 0  , 40],
F [45, 35 , 45, 51, 86 ,  0],
```

But depending on a specific input I will only need to take certain points. For example my input is [A,B, E, F] (which should be a list from a df ) that will need to return the next matrix:

```
   A    B   E    F
A [0 ,  1 , 60 ,100],
B [4 ,  0 , 29 , 98],
E [33, 34 , 0  , 40],
F [45, 35 , 86 ,  0],
```

The "big" matrix is as big as 1100 x 1100 and the "small" one can become as small as 130x130, so its a lot of information to process, and this needs to be done daily so it has to be a fast process. I have no idea where to start. All of this should be in python FYI

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: the data inside the matrixes are floats, but the inputs (A,B,C,D,E or F) are strings always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use numpy, the solution is even simpler as the one proposed by Alexandr:

```
import numpy as np

source = np.array([
    [0, 1, 3, 20, 60, 100],
    [4, 0, 7, 95, 29, 98],
    [6, 5, 0, 36, 68, 120],
    [12, 97, 3, 0, 94, 30],
    [33, 34, 87, 34, 0, 40],
    [45, 35, 45, 51, 86, 0]])

need = (0, 1, 4, 5)

print(source[need,...][...,need])
```

provides

```
[[  0   1  60 100]
 [  4   0  29  98]
 [ 33  34   0  40]
 [ 45  35  86   0]]
```

**EDIT :** I forgot another handy numpy operator called `ix_` which enables exactly the kind of complex indexing we need here. So replace the last line of my previous solution by the following one:

```
print(source[np.ix_(need, need)])
```

Some quick benchmarking shows almost a 10x speedup (using a 1100x1100 matrix) compared to my previous proposal, as it does not need the creation of an intermediate array

Comment: I'll test both process and I'll let you know!

Answer (score 1):

Here we are. It requires the source matrix and required columns list for slicing it.

```
from pprint import pprint

source = [
    [0, 1, 3, 20, 60, 100],
    [4, 0, 7, 95, 29, 98],
    [6, 5, 0, 36, 68, 120],
    [12, 97, 3, 0, 94, 30],
    [33, 34, 87, 34, 0, 40],
    [45, 35, 45, 51, 86, 0],
]

need = [0, 1, 4, 5]

print('Source matrix')
pprint(source, width=30)

result = [[source[i][x] for x in need] for i in need]

print('Resulting matrix')
pprint(result, width=30)
```

Outputs

```
Source matrix
[[0, 1, 3, 20, 60, 100],
 [4, 0, 7, 95, 29, 98],
 [6, 5, 0, 36, 68, 120],
 [12, 97, 3, 0, 94, 30],
 [33, 34, 87, 34, 0, 40],
 [45, 35, 45, 51, 86, 0]]
Resulting matrix
[[0, 1, 60, 100],
 [4, 0, 29, 98],
 [33, 34, 0, 40],
 [45, 35, 86, 0]]
```

> It makes a `squared slice` as requested from the question required output.

Comment: I'll test both process and I'll let you know!